# How do I avoid a high DC current flowing through mosfet in my SRSSTC tesla coil?

Tags: mosfet, powermosfet, tesla-coil

[image]

There are 6.48 amps flowing through the mosfet but only 12 mA through the capacitor, L2 would be my tesla coil primary.
How can I reduce the amount of components in my circuit and improve its performance? I need a high AC high frequency current flow through the tesla coil's primary.

Comment: Where are  your specs ? goals?  f, Vp , Ip, VAR, Pd?  budget?

Comment: i want the primary coil to have only one turn because the secondary is just 200 turns, so i calculated that it should run at 58 MHz so there is  a high enough reactance if there is no load on the secondary, in the simulation there are high frequency bursts now that i improved the circuit a little but my problem is that there is very little AC current in the primary, just 10 mA. For the budget part, this is with components that i already have so i wont spend anything.